# Getting error when connecting to Tableau through MongoDB BI Connector

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-connection, tableau-api

I am trying to connect MongoDB stored at Azure Cloud with Tableau for my analysis using MongoDB BI Connector. 
Step 1 I have created a schema with mongodrdl.exe

```
mongodrdl.exe /host:<MONGO-SERVER> /port:<MONGO-PORT> -d <MONGO-COLLECTION> 
-o <DRDL-SCHEMA-PATH> /ssl /username:<MONGO-USER> /password:<MONGO- 
PASSWORD>
```

Step 2  mongosqld started:

```
mongosqld.exe --schema <DRDL-SCHEMA-PATH> --mongo-uri mongodb://<MONGO- 
SERVER>:<MONGO-PORT> /mongo-username:<MONGO-USER> /mongo-password:<MONGO- 
PASSWORD> /mongo-ssl --auth
```

Step 3 connect to Tableau with help of MongoDB BI Connector (Server localhost, port 3307)

at this moment I get handshake error: ERROR 1759 (HY000): ssl is required when using cleartext authentication

the question is why did I get this error? How to install ssl in this case, any advise is appreciated.

Comment: There is another way to connect data from MongoDB to Tableau also with community edition, I have described it here:  https://medium.com/@katya.neulinger/tableau-web-data-connector-to-mongodb-c1477d7d5ac9